# How to store .each() function return value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically checking chekboxes by using below function.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('checked', true);   
});
```

I want to store whole checked checkboxes in string.

Comment: `var $checkes = $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);`

Comment: what do you mean by in a string, do you need the id/name of the checkboxes

Comment: Use `.prop()` instead. You could use `.attr('checked', 'checked')` too.

Comment: Assume all the above function checks all checkboxes of a list.  
 I want to get that whole in string.

Comment: @AlekhyaVemavarapu `I want to get that whole in string??` Do you need to get all checkboxs id/name as Arun P Jhony said??

Comment: `var boxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]').filter(function() { return this.checked });`

Comment: Not sure what you're after. How [about this](http://jsfiddle.net/b07t7wk6/1/)?

Answer (score 1):

```
var ids =''
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('checked')=='checked'){
        ids += $(this).attr(id) + ',';
    } 
});
```

You may also then split ids by comma and acquire an array of IDs

```
var ids = ids.split(',')
```

Comment: `var ids = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() { return this.id; }).get();` is much shorter